# Component footprint symbol cross-reference / cheat sheet / appnote?

Tags: pcb-design, component-selection, footprint

While shopping for components I've noticed different manufacturers / suppliers will use different names / codes for identical footprints, which can make it a chore to work out what will actually fit - especially in these supply-constrained times, it's a pain.

For example, the following are all used to describe the same component footprint:

- SOT223
- TO-261AA
- SC-73

And often a supplier will treat them as discrete incompatible versions depending on who input the data / how each manufacturer writes their datasheet.

So, does anyone know of a good quick-reference guide, cheat-sheet, table, appnote, poster, or T-shirt that lists all of these (or as many as practical) in a clear and concise way?

It feels like the sort of thing that there MUST be out there somewhere, yet googling does not turn up any great info.

Comment: What a great idea for a T-shirt

Answer (score 2):

https://www.topline.tv/sot_leadfree.html  might solve some of your issues.
https://www.topline.tv/dummycomp.pdf

You can probably design a better one. [image]

Comment: +1 Looks like a great resource. I had no idea you could make a business out of selling dummy components.

Comment: We used them to thermal profile new SMT boards when I was Eng Mgr at C-MAC EMS, FWIW @ElliotAlderson

Comment: the t-shirt needs to be printed in mirror image, or upside down, so it's easier to read ... lol